# Are licensed file geodatabase restrictions/permissions inherited when converting in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml, file-geodatabase, kmz

If I create a licensed file geodatabase and I convert a feature class within in it as KMZ/KML file through the conversion tool, will it inherit the restrictions that I created within the licensed filegeodatabase?

Answer (score 2):

Currently not, per Esri's [Generated License File Geodatabase](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-licensed-file-geodatabase.htm)

> You cannot license individual feature classes or tables to produce a mixed state where some feature classes or tables are licensed and others are not. However, a licensed file geodatabase allows you to add an unlicensed feature class or table through operations such as creating a new, empty feature class, copying and pasting, or importing a feature class.

Comment: So basically if I generate a license file geodatabase will not resolve my query which I have posted in another thread, i.e. my intent of applying copying restrictions to a kmz/kml that I created in ArcMap. So it seems there is no solution to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It will remain restricted within the File geodatabase, if you are thinking to add the KMZ/KML to the file geodatabase withe the license restriction, then export the KMZ/KML as it's own file to share with those restrictions, I don't think that is possible at this time.